# How to use youtube-dl script to download starting from some index in a playlist?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

How to download playlist using `youtube-dl` from start certain number to an upper limit?

I tried to use in the code:

```
youtube-dl -o '~/Documents/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' URL
```

and it stopped in the middle. I want to restart the process from the index `i`th numbered video, and not have it start over from the beginning.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`youtube-dl --help`, [contains](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#video-selection):

> ```
> Video Selection:
>   --playlist-start NUMBER          Playlist video to start at (default is 1)
>   --playlist-end NUMBER            Playlist video to end at (default is last)
>   --playlist-items ITEM_SPEC       Playlist video items to download. Specify
>                                    indices of the videos in the playlist
>                                    separated by commas like: "--playlist-items
>                                    1,2,5,8" if you want to download videos
>                                    indexed 1, 2, 5, 8 in the playlist. You can
>                                    specify range: "--playlist-items
>                                    1-3,7,10-13", it will download the videos
>                                    at index 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 12 and 13.
> ```

Thus, the option `--playlist-start NUMBER` should help you to start the playlist in the middle, specified by `NUMBER`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.. but how do I count the video from a certain number? This downloads me the right video but from number 1 and not from the NUMBER number I inserted

Answer (score 19):

I have total 135 videos in my playlist. I have successfully downloaded 38 of them. So I manually used this command.

```
youtube-dl --playlist-start 39 -u uname@gmail.com -p mypassword https://www.udemy.com/learn-ethical-hacking-from-scratch/learn/v4/content
```

Its downloading my remaining 97 videos.

Comment: I am getting 
`ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14
07742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version> (caused
 by URLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERV
ER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),))`  could you please help me download the videos.

Comment: @HunterrJ can you please mention the command that you are using to download

Comment: I tried, `D:\tutorials>youtube-dl -u email -p password https://www.udemy.com/data-analysis-with-pandas/learn/v4/`

Comment: @HunterrJ have you tried appending "--playlist-start 1" to start from the first video?

Comment: @HunterrJ First you have to install the python script then only you can run the command

Comment: Even I tried executing the python script.
`def youtube(url):
 import youtube_dl

 ydl_opts = {
  'verbose': False,
  'format': '22/best',
  'outtmpl': '%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s',
  'noplaylist': False,
  'playliststart' : 1,
  'u':'username',
  'p':'password'
 }
 with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
  ydl.download([url])`

Still throws same error.

Answer (score 1):

This helped:

```
youtube-dl -f best <playlist link> --playlist-start 15
```

-f best selects the best video formats. use youtube-dl --help for more options

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of the above answers. If you are looking only to download the audio formats like m4a, then following command will work best. Even with playlist, and providing the start and end indices. Also the M4a format file size is smaller.

```
youtube-dl -i -f mp4 --yes-playlist --playlist-start 'start_index' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vy8970q0Xc&list=PLwJ2VKmefmxpUJEGB1ff6yUZ5Zd7Gegn2'
```

Using the inbuilt audio formats before ffmpeg can reduce the time required to enjoy the music or the video. In background you can get a better formats